# How to find the first occurrence of a boolean value for a given day using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

`(Not duplicate / I did my research)`

My `minute-based` `dataframe` looks like this:

```
time,                  price_bool,    price_date
2017-01-01 00:00:00,   False, 
2017-01-01 00:01:00,   False, 
2017-01-01 00:02:00,   True,          2017-01-01 00:02:00
2017-01-01 00:03:00,   False, 
2017-01-01 00:04:00,   False, 
2017-01-01 00:05:00,   True,          2017-01-01 00:05:00
....
```

Right now it is a `minute-based` dataset. I want to `group` by `day` by the `first` occurrence of `True` and skip to another `day` once the first `True` is found. If there are no `True` in a given `minute-based` dataset, then that `day` will have `0` on the `price_date`.

My new `dataframe` should look like this:

```
time,                  price_bool,    price_date
2017-01-01 00:00:00,   True,          2017-01-01 00:02:00
2017-01-02 00:00:00,   True,          2017-01-02 00:07:00
2017-01-03 00:00:00,   True,          2017-01-03 02:21:00
2017-01-04 00:00:00,   True,          2017-01-04 01:17:00
....
```

This is the `day` based dataset where `price_bool` is `True` and corrsponding `price_date` when it was first `True` for a given `day`

**What did I do?**

- First I tried to remove the `empty` field
- After that, I tried to `groupby('time')`

However, it does not work.

Comment: you need to group by the "day".. try converting the time to pd.Timestamp(time).day and group by that

Comment: I already did `pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time'], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Can you share part of your dataframe as dict so i can create sample dataframe. You can do df.head(10).values

Comment: `df.sort_values('time').sort_values('price_bool', ascending = False).groupby(df['time'].dt.date).first()`

Comment: @BrianJoseph Looks like your solution works. You should submit as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: @floss, thanks, I forget sometimes haha and no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler starting data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["2017-01-01 00:00:00",False,pd.np.nan], 
    ["2017-01-01 00:00:01",True,"2017-01-01 00:00:01"], 
    ["2017-01-01 00:00:02",True,"2017-01-01 00:00:01"],
    ["2017-01-02 00:00:00",False,pd.np.nan], 
], columns=['time','price_bool','price_date'])
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

This should get you the data you show in your result (note this assumes you're already sorted in chronological order):

```
res = df[df['price_bool'] == True].groupby(df['time'].dt.date)[['price_bool','price_date']].first().reset_index()
```

However, I think you're saying that you want to keep dates with `price_bool` false and have the `price_date` be `0` in that case.  So you would need to add back the dates that are missing in `res` above.  Here's one option:

```
# Get the True data set right.
res = df[df['price_bool'] == True].groupby(df['time'].dt.date)[['price_bool','price_date']].first()
# Add back the missing dates with only False values
res = res.reindex(df['time'].dt.date.unique()).reset_index()
# Fill in the null values.
res = res.fillna({'price_bool':False, 'price_date':0})
```

Out (note I created a simpler starting data set):

```
        time    price_bool  price_date
0   2017-01-01  True    2017-01-01 00:00:01
1   2017-01-02  False   0
```

Comment: Thank you, That is a great solution. Could you also please help me find the difference between between `time` and `price_date` in mins?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.sort_values('time').sort_values('price_bool', ascending = False).groupby(df['time'].dt.date).first()
```

Output with your provided df:

```
>>> df
time        price_bool
2017-01-01  True
```

**Explanation**: You want to sort by two columns: `time` and `price_bool`. The latter needs to be sorted in reverse as you want `True` to appear before `False`. Then, since groupby preserves sorting, you can simply select the first element from each group after grouping by date.

Comment: What about the `time` that is `False`?  it should get `0` value instead of `time`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
first_true_daily = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='D'))['price_bool'].idxmax()

df.loc[first_true_daily]
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence`